# xInput Mouse Sensitivity Units.

Tags: xubuntu, mouse

I have a 400 dpi mouse, and I was wondering how the final arument in the following command works. 
 `xinput set-prop 11 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" X`

What would the effective dpi be if I picked 1 vs 2, etc.

Is it a multiplier?

My goal is to have my mouse do 1:1 with my computer, how would I achieve that?